# Android: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, deprecated

Inside my Activity I am instantiating an object which is responsible to query, process and store the data needed by the fragments. I was about to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` in order to retain the object after configuration changes, but I just realized the method has been deprecated.

I can see that the new recommended way is to use Fragment's `setRetainInstance()`, but it doesn't look like it's what I need, because my object doesn't deal with just 1 fragment.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because my object doesn't deal with just 1 fragment

No, but your fragment can deal with whatever the object is.

`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` requires you to package everything into one object. Consider the retained fragment strategy to be requiring that this "one object" be a fragment, on which you call `setRetainInstance()`. Anything you could do with `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` should be doable with a retained fragment.

Comment: I am not sure. On the `setRetainInstance()` documentation it says: "This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack":
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29
So, this means that if I am accessing fragment B from fragment A, so that fragment A goes into the back stack, I cannot use the object retained by A to populate the data in fragment B.

Comment: @DanieleB: Then retain Fragment C. This does not have to be one of your existing fragments. It does not need to have a UI. Add it to your `FragmentManager` via [the `add()` on `FragmentTransaction` that takes a tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) and retrieve it later by tag. This is the so-called "model fragment" pattern.

Comment: I see... it could a solution... do you have any documentation/article about this "model fragment" pattern? Thanks

Comment: @DanieleB: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding (see "Adding a fragment without a UI"). The term "model fragment" was from an I/O 2011 presentation, IIRC.